# How to list an erc20 token in an exchange site?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, erc-20, myetherwallet, etherscan

An erc20 token has been smart contracted in `MyEtherWallet`(Ropsten) and verified & published in `etherscan.io`. I want to list this token in an exchange I've built. Can I do it by installing a private blockchain(geth) in my exchange server and able to do rpc calls like it's done for ETH? If it is not possible, what are the other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to setup a local Geth instance and start it in `testnet` non-mining mode as described in [Ropsten docs](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten/blob/master/README.md).

Wait for it to sync, then you'll be able to access it via RPC (WS-RPC is needed to be able to subscribe to new events, HTTP-RPC can be used for listing past events).

Then you can subscribe to and list the `Transfer` events of your contact using the ERC20 ABI.

Comment: Thank you Rusty. Could you elaborate why http-rpc won't work?

Comment: Can I do real-time trades on testnet instance?

Comment: Http-rpc is request-reply, for asynchronous events you need websocket protocol. You can do trades using your local instance, provided you use a funded account and specify some gas amount. Only funded transactions get propagated through the network, also in a testnet.

Comment: I read that testnets are for only testing purpose. Does a testnet become mainnet if we apply gas price for it? If that is true, is it applicable for only erc20-tokens?

Comment: A testnet is like a mainnet except its ether is worthless. Instead of mining testnet ether, the testnet gives it out for free to anyone interested. The main principle of paying for gas though is still the same. A testnet never becomes mainnet.